Find and remove some bytes in very big files
I am working with some digital archeology and recovered some information from tapes. The files are very big (gigabytes). As archive software is very old and maybe proprietary, I want to write some custom tools.
I need to find byte sequence in file and remove it (copy to other file without it). There several types of byte sequences to remove (it is backup software markers. There is header and some random stuff like checksum, known length).
Then I need to split file using another byte markers to many files. I can detect header, but can not decoder data in it, so I slit between headers. Size of files- from few kilobytes to hundreds of megabytes.
I have done this using MS visual basic, but using "read all bytes". So I have 2 gigabytes limit.
Maybe there is easy (and fast) way to do this reading file in portions using some "FileSystem.Seek Method" like in old computers?
some of my dirty tricks:
    Private Structure Radom
        Dim startas As List(Of Integer)
        Dim stopas As List(Of Integer)
    End Structure

Private Function FindIt(ByRef bytes As Byte(), ByRef search As Byte(), limitas As UInt32) As Radom
    Dim index As Int32
    Dim i As UInt32 = 0
    Dim l As UInt32 = 0
    Dim z As Radom
    z.startas = New List(Of Integer)
    z.stopas = New List(Of Integer)
    
    While index < limitas - 5 And index >= 0
        index = Array.IndexOf(bytes, search(0), index)
        If index < 0 Then
            Exit While
        End If

        If Confirmdit(bytes, search, index) Then

            index += search.Length
            If (i > 0) Then
                z.startas.Add(l)
                z.stopas.Add(index - search.Length)
            End If
            l = index - search.Length
            i += 1
        End If
        index += 1
    End While

    If l > 0 Then
        z.startas.Add(l)
        z.stopas.Add(limitas - 1)
    End If
    Return z

End Function
Private Function Confirmdit(ByRef buferis As Byte(), ByRef ieskom As Byte(), start As UInt32) As Boolean
    Dim b As Boolean = True
    For i = 0 To ieskom.Length - 1
        If start + i > buferis.Length - 1 Then
            b = False
            Exit For
        End If
        If buferis(start + i) <> ieskom(i) Then
            b = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Confirmdit = b
End Function

After reading answers I created this. But there is problem- I found 26315 byte sequences vs 26156 found using whole buffer read (and HexEdit software found 26156 too) in 1.7Gig file.. Repaired.
Private Function IndexFile(filename As String) As Radom
    Dim z As Radom
    Dim k As Radom
    Dim tmp_c As Integer = 0
    Const C_ROLLBACK As UInteger = 200 'must be bigger than searchable bytes
    z.startas = New List(Of Integer)
    z.stopas = New List(Of Integer)

    Dim buferis(&H1000000) As Byte
    Dim ReadBytes As Int32
    Dim currentpos As Int32 = 0
    Dim i As Integer

    Using fsSrc As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H1000000)
        While currentpos < fsSrc.Length
            ReadBytes = fsSrc.Read(buferis, 0, &H1000000)

            k = FindIt(buferis, magic0, ReadBytes) ' (source buffer, bytes to find, search lenght)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(k.startas.Count.ToString + vbCrLf)
            tmp_c += k.startas.Count
            For i = 0 To k.startas.Count - 1
                If z.startas.BinarySearch(k.startas(i) + currentpos) < 0 Then
                    z.startas.Add(k.startas(i) + currentpos)
                    z.stopas.Add(k.stopas(i) + currentpos)
                End If
            Next

            currentpos += ReadBytes
            If currentpos < fsSrc.Length Then
                currentpos = fsSrc.Seek(-C_ROLLBACK, SeekOrigin.Current)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("VISO:" + tmp_c.ToString + vbCrLf)
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("NVISO:" + z.startas.Count.ToString + vbCrLf)
    Return z
End Function

When going to bigger files, many int32 and uint32 must be changed to 64 bit values. Note, the array.search is working only with signed int32, limiting buffer sizes to 2G max.
As far, looks like file indexing is working. And quite fast.

File seek definitely still exists :) - Allocating a buffer and processing a buffer-sized chunk at a time should not be hard to do. You would need to take care around delimiters straddling two buffer pages, but that should not be too difficult either.

N.B. VB.NET uses the index of the last element of the array in the declaration, so Dim buferis(&H1000000) As Byte has &H1000001 elements.

You can use a FileStream for this:
Const BUFFER_SIZE_CONST As Integer = 4096
Dim binaryFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Junk.txt")
Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
Using fs As New FileStream(binaryFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, BUFFER_SIZE_CONST)
  fs.Seek(1000, SeekOrigin.Begin)
  Dim bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE_CONST)
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(buffer))
End Using

You will need to add code to look for your search term, check the number of bytes returned, etc.

Thanks all for help. Current version of file indexing is working. Tested with 4Gbytes file and looks like all segments are found. The source code in the first post tested and is good. Do not forget to change variables to 64 bits when working with 2G+ files.
